# How to fill out the null values of a column with the first non null value of that column in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to fill out the null values of a column of a dataframe with the first value that is not null of that same column.

The dataframe that I want to fill out looks like this, and I want all the rows of the column 'id_book' to have the same number

[image: 1]

I have tried the following but it still shows the null values

```
w = Window.partitionBy('id_book').orderBy('id_book', 'date').rowsBetween(0,sys.maxsize)
filled_column = first(spark_df['id_book'], ignorenulls=True).over(w)
spark_df_filled = union_dias.withColumn('id_book_filled_spark', filled_column)
```

Answer (score 0):

The window should be

```
w = Window.orderBy('date').rowsBetween(0, Window.unboundedFollowing)
filled_column = first(spark_df['id_book'], ignorenulls=True).over(w)
spark_df_filled = spark_df.withColumn('id_book_filled_spark', filled_column)
```

Because you don't want to partition by `id_book`. There is also no point to order by `id_book` because only the order of the date matters.

Also I think the better practice is to use `Window.unboundedFollowing` instead of `sys.maxsize`.